# Formatting time with boost chrono

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I wonder if is there any way to get only the time without printing out the units :

```cpp
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::chrono::milliseconds sumGlobal;

int main() {
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 ;
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 ;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    { 
        t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        f(); //to waste time   
        t2 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sumGlobal += (boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1)); 
    }          

    std::cout << sumGlobal << "\n";        
}
```

the Output is :

```
123 milliseconds
```

I'd like to get only

```
123
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: TIL boost chrono time units have overloaded streaming operators. I wonder about the localization and other things (like simplification, pluralization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`milliseconds` is a template instantiation of the `duration` class template:

```
typedef duration<boost::int_least64_t, milli> milliseconds;
```

The stream output operator `<<` is overloaded for the `duration` class:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Rep, class Period>
    std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
```

Given the template parameters of your case, the provided version by default adds the unit "milliseconds" as text.

But the [duration class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.duration_hpp.duration) has the method `count` that will return you the duration in the specified unit (in your case milliseconds) as the specified integer type (the `rep` type parameter, in your case `boost::int_least64_t`):

```
constexpr rep count() const;
```

You can output that integer number in your own format (in your case just the pure number):

```
std::cout << sumGlobal.count() << std::endl;
```

Comment: "and there is nothing you can do about it" is not true; there's a lot of customizability by using custom `duration_units` facets

Comment: @sehe: Edited to a more careful statement.